# Debian system upgrade with cron

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, updates, cron

I understand that the question should one perform automated and unattended system upgrades is highly debatable, but let us assume that I for one, never had any issues with that concept so far.

The setup is the following: stripped down `Debian` based server system, running, for example `Apache` and `SSH` servers, properly protected with very strict `iptables` rules and behind a HW `firewall`. There is a daily `cron` job that does the following:

```
apt-get update &&
apt-get upgrade -y &&
apt-get dist-upgrade -y &&
apt-get autoremove -y &&
service apache restart &&
service ssh restart
```

The idea behind this is: if there is an update to the software that is the only attack surface to the outer world, install it and restart that software. (The restart occurs even if Apache and SSH weren't upgraded, and the service downtime at that point is less than a second).

Now, my problem is, when there is an update to `Apache` and `SSH`, `dpkg` asks whether one should keep the original configuration or replace it with the generic, default one. Unfortunately this is a menu-based prompt and one cannot use simple pipe to `yes` to select the proper answer. Any ideas how can this be scripted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try '-qq -y', but it is **not** recommended.

> -q, --quiet
>   Quiet. Produces output suitable for logging, omitting progress indicators. More q's will produce more quiet up to a maximum of two. You can also use -q=# to set the quiet level, overriding the configuration file. Note that quiet level 2 implies -y, you should never use -qq without a no-action modifier such as -d, --print-uris or -s as APT may decided to do something you did not expect.

I guess it would be best to simulate the upgrade first, and then decide if it is *'safe'* to force an upgrade or not, that is if force is necessary.

**Simulate:**

```
# apt-get -qq -s upgrade
```

**Force upgrade:**

```
# apt-get -qq -y upgrade
```

Reference;

[**apt-get man**](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [debian handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.package-meta-information.html) you can avoid the configuration file questions by adding the following line :

```
DPkg::options { "--force-confdef"; "--force-confold"; }
```

To your `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local` file (create the `local` file before )

Or include the above option in the `apt` command :

```
apt -o DPkg::options::="--force-confdef" -o DPkg::options::="--force-confold" full-upgrade
```

> GOING FURTHER **Avoiding the configuration file questions**
>
> `dpkg` handles configuration file updates, but, while doing so, regularly interrupts its work to ask for input from the administrator. This makes it less than enjoyable for those who wish to run updates in a non-interactive manner. This is why this program offers options that allow the system to respond automatically according to the same logic: `--force-confold` retains the old version of the file; `--force-confnew` will use the new version of the file (these choices are respected, even if the file has not been changed by the administrator, which only rarely has the desired effect). Adding the `--force-confdef` option tells `dpkg` to decide by itself when possible (in other words, when the original configuration file has not been touched), and only uses `--force-confnew` or `--force-confold` for other cases.